# Flyway command line filesystem migrations from actual command line input

Tags: windows, flyway

I'm trying out Flyway as a possible way to do database migrations.

Because I am supporting multiple databases and potentially running migration jobs for different environments and databases simultaneously, I need the ability to use the command line tool without referencing the config (properties) file for my SQL migrations location. Is there a way to do this? It appears to only read from the default location or from the location specified in the flyway.properties file.

My install directory is C:\flyway. I'm running this on a Windows server with the command below:

flyway.cmd migrate -url=jdbc:sqlserver://%URL%;databaseName=%DB% -user=%USER% -password=%PW% -schemas=dbo -initOnMigrate=true -locations filesystem:C:/Steve -jarDir filesystem:filesystem:C:/flyway/jars

It's a great tool. I really hope that I will be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

flyway.cmd -configFile=/path/to/other/configFile.conf should do what you want. I just checked and it seems I forgot to document this on the website (It is in the usage description of the tool itself).

Could you file an issue against the website, requesting this to be added?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will file an issue as you request. Unfortunately, just pointing to different config files will not work in my situation. I am a

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was cut off...Thank you for your reply. I will file an issue as you request. Unfortunately, just pointing to different config files will not work in my situation. The SQL directories are created while being pulled from Rational Asset Mgr. as part of a larger build/deploy job, so the name is always different. However, I may be able to copy and edit the config file on the fly and use the edited version while calling Flyway. Thank you for the idea.